# Adapter getView() not being called for all items

Tags: android

I have a list view backed by a custom adapter.  The adapter has 17 items in it's items list, but only shows the first 2.  I have traced through `getView()` and confirmed that it is only being called for positions 0 and 1.

Populating the adapter and setting it in `onCreate()` of the parent `Activity`.

```
FavouritesListAdapter adapter = new FavouritesListAdapter(favourites, this);

((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // not needed but put here out of desperation!
```

The adapter signature and `getView()` method:

```
public class FavouritesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Favourite> entries;

    public FavouritesListAdapter(ArrayList<Favourite> favourites, Context context) {
        this.entries = favourites;
        this.context = context;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RelativeLayout rl;

    Log.d(LOG_DEBUG_TAG, "Count:" + getCount() ", asking for pos " + position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite_tide_table, null);
        convertView = rl;

    } else { // convertView is not null (it's being recycled)

        Favourite thisFavourite = this.getItem(position);

        convertView = thisFavourite.getPortView();

    }

    return convertView;

}
```

The logcat output:

```
Count:17, asking for pos 0
Count:17, asking for pos 0
Count:17, asking for pos 0
Count:17, asking for pos 1
Count:17, asking for pos 0
Count:17, asking for pos 0
```

The activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#FF0000"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</ScrollView>
```

The first two items are properly displayed.

What have I missed?  Thanks!

Comment: how many rows have you at screen

Comment: don't put a listview in a scrollview. it doesn't work.

Comment: @njzk2  Doh, doh, doh!  I can't believe how stupid that was!  How many list views have I done?  Thanks.  If you want the rep, please post your comment as an answer (which is good for future visitors anyway) and I'll accept.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListView` cannot go into a `ScrollView`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing) from Romain Guy. More details in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) video from google I/O

If you really need to put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`, you basically need the `ListView` to know its height, which is possible using DougW answer to the mentionned question.